# why code after the return statement is reachable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript , and i have one confusion.
 As we always  taught that code after the return statement is unreachable.
But this is not true in below case and i am not able to understand why its so.

```
function foo() {

  //define bar once
  function bar() {
      return 3;
  }

  //redefine it
  function bar() {
      return 8;
  }

  //return its invocation
  return bar(); //8
}
alert(foo());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jainhimanshu/euga4mcy/
and output is 8 but it should be 3.

So can anyone clear me the concept.

Comment: Essentially, you are saying: `x = 3` then `x = 8`.  So why are you expecting `x == 3`?

Comment: @Johan Sorry, but no.  It never says `x = 3`.  The first function is never called as it's overwritten by the second one.

Comment: @Archer fine, `bar = 3` then `bar = 8` then `return bar`... is exactly what I said and what is written out above.

Comment: @Johan - no you're misunderstanding me.  The first `bar()` function doesn't exist as it's overridden by the second.  Literally, it is never called so there is never a return value of 3.  It's 8 and only 8.

Comment: Hi @Johan if we do like this  http://jsfiddle.net/jainhimanshu/euga4mcy/1/ then also its output is 8 , why its so

Comment: @HimanshuJain The first `bar()` function is effectively being destroyed when you declare it the second time.  There is no `bar()` function that will return the value of 3.

Comment: @Archer yes, I get that, I simplified the problem, so that it was easier to understand.

Comment: @HimanshuJain That's because [_hoisting_](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092)

Comment: @Johan - no it would never, ever return 3.  Ever.  He's just highlighted that exact fact with his fiddle link.  That function is gone, regardless of when it's called.

Comment: @Archer yes, always 8.

Comment: but what we learn in c# language that once the return statement occurs then we comes out of the scope and output becomes what we get from current scope.....but this will not in the case of javascript

Comment: @HimanshuJain The declarations are hoisted(moved to the top). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)  http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: @HimanshuJain `foo()` has a return statement and that is the last thing executed in **that** function.  `bar()`  has a return statment and that is the last thing executed in **that** function.  It is doing exactly the same as C# - there is no difference here.  See the correct and more detailed answer from Tushar below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you've to call the function to get the `return` value from it.

The function `bar` is not called, it is only defined.

So, when the function `foo()` is called

```
return bar();
```

from `foo` is executed and `8` is returned.

The Compiler sees the `foo` as follow(after overriding the `bar`):

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        return 8;
    }

    return bar();
}
alert(foo());
```

When `return bar()` is reached, the function `bar` is called and it's value is returned.

After invocation of `bar`

```
function foo() {
    return 8;
}
alert(foo());
```

Comment: Hi @Tushar , i understand the hoisting , but cannot able to mug one thing that how one function override the definition of another function definition and suppose if the definition of two function is different but there name is same ,then what the result. Please explore

Comment: @HimanshuJain The function which is defined earlier is overriden by the later, this is what is happening in your case

Comment: yes @Tushar that i understand but what happened if the function definition is totally different but the function name is same then again they earlier is overriden by later function

Comment: @HimanshuJain Yes. Run this in `console`. `function a(a, b) { alert('In first'); } function a () { alert('In second'); }a();`

Comment: one last question @Tushar , now i understand that earlier function is overridden by later function . but what we have done in earlier function is still exist or it will completely be overridden by  later function i.e we get combine part of two function or the only later function in result when we call the function

Comment: @HimanshuJain It's completely overriden. If you want to extend it, you can use something like this `function a(a, b) { alert('In first'); } function aa () { a(); alert('In second'); }aa();`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89155/discussion-between-himanshu-jain-and-tushar).

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(){
  // ....
}
```

creates new [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), and assignees name `foo` to it. It is still no where called, just created, so any return statement will not be triggered.

When inside this function you create new `Functions`, like

```
function foo(){
  function bar() {
    return 3;
  }
  return 4;
}
// after you execute foo
console.log(foo()); // will log 4
```

But very important that inside this lexical scope, function `bar` is created, but no where executed. See also [Lexical scope](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_04.htm)

But when you have this

```
function foo(){
  function bar(){
    return 3;
  }
  function bar() {
    return 8;
  }
  return bar();
}
// after you execute foo
console.log(foo()); // will log 8
```

When you execute function `foo` inside `global` scope, it creates Function object named `bar`, then it creates new Function object named `bar`, the old one is redefined, same as assigning new value to `variable`, value changes, but in this context function body that is assigned to Function name has change.

Because your function `foo` has `return` keyword, it returns that value. Value that it returns is value that returns function `bar`, as `return bar();` will execute function `bar` and return value it receives from function `bar`, in example it is value 8.

Compare variable redefinition with function redefinition

```
var a;
a = "some string";
a = 5; // a has value 5, no mater older values
// same goes for functions
function bar(){ .... }
function bar(){ .... }
function bar(){ .... }
// invoke bar
bar(); // last function bar will be executed, no mater other function's bar definitions
```

Comment: Hi @Nermin , I understand your point but what happened if the definition of two functions bar which is defined inside the function foo is totally different then , how they will be redefined  and what will be the output.